# Android native libc signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr

Tags: android, c++, debugging

I've been experiencing crash after adding following code:

```
class AudioPolicyService :
    public BinderService<AudioPolicyService>,
    public BnAudioPolicyService,
    public IBinder::DeathRecipient
{
    friend class BinderService<AudioPolicyService>;

//[....]
    class TestingClz : public virtual RefBase {
        public:
            TestingClz (String8 name, const wp<AudioPolicyService>& service){}
            virtual TestingClz() {}
    };

    sp<TestingClz> mTestingClz;
} // End of class AudioPolicyService

//[....]

void AudioPolicyService::onFirstRef()
{
...
TestingClz = new TestingClz(String8("test"), this);
}
```

I got following crash:

> 02-03 22:21:17.971   367   367 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.971   367   367 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.971   367   367 F DEBUG   : pid: 981, tid: 981, name:
>   mediaserver  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.972   367   367 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2
>   (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xb6e594d8
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.976   367   367 F DEBUG   :     r0 b6e594d8  r1
>   becfa970  r2 00000000  r3 b6e4d812
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.976   367   367 F DEBUG   :     r4 b5fd6a1c  r5
>   becfa970  r6 becfa96c  r7 b5fd69d4
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.976   367   367 F DEBUG   :     r8 becfa968  r9
>   b6ad8e2d  sl 00000000  fp becfabbc
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.976   367   367 F DEBUG   :     ip b6b0ec24  sp
>   becfa958  lr b6b03849  pc b6b03604  cpsr 80010030
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000e604 
>   /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::weakref_type::incWeak(void
>   const*)+11)
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0000e845 
>   /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::createWeak(void const*)
>   const+6)
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 000060ad 
>   /system/lib/libaudiopolicyservice.so
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000620b 
>   /system/lib/libaudiopolicyservice.so
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0000232d 
>   /system/bin/mediaserver
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.980   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00001b8f 
>   /system/bin/mediaserver
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.981   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00017359 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
>
> 02-03 22:21:17.981   367   367 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00001e0c 
>   /system/bin/mediaserver
>
> 02-03 22:21:18.088   367   367 F DEBUG   :
>
> 02-03 22:21:18.088   367   367 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to:
>   /data/tombstones/tombstone_01

After mapping address to line, it points to the lines out of my change.
`SEGV_ACCERR` means invalid permissions for mapped object. I was wondering whether it is caused by android mprotect? As it doesn't seem like a normal crash.
Have anyone experienced the same failure? Thanks a lot!

Update:
OK, it seems the crash is not happening if I make a whole build and flash the system&boot images.
So, to make a android native service change, we'll always need a full build?

Denon

Answer (score 0):

Result:
it seems the crash is not happening if I make a whole build and flash the system&boot images. 
However, I was still wondering if there's certain protection mechanism to record and verify the class size at run-time. It seems the binary address mapping is still not updated even if we replace the .so lib.

Thanks for any further information!